# Problem using axios on mobile browsers on production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I using the axios to fetch a user from the backend. In the localhost, and laptop browsers, everything works. But on mobile, the phone does not extract the data from the server.
I create a context file which I am using to get the user data from all the available components.
In the use effect function, I have a function that decided if the site is in production or development. and returns the production link or the development localhost and assign the right endpoint.

````
export const userContext = createContext({});
const Context = props => {

    const [userState, setUserState] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(getProductionURL('/api/get-user'), { withCredentials: true })
            .then(res => {
                if (res?.data) {
                    setUserState(res.data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
              alert('Error')
            });
    }, []);


  return (
    <userContext.Provider value={userState}>{ props.children }</userContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Context


export function getProductionURL(endpoint) {
    const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://car-share-ride-a7b2b849cd69.herokuapp.com' : 'http://localhost:3000';
    
    if (endpoint) return baseURL + endpoint;
    else return baseURL;
}

```;



On the profile page I simply use the user context to get the data:
````

const Profile = () => {
const myUserContext = useContext(userContext);
const navigate = useNavigate();
console.log(myUserContext);

return (

{ myUserContext?.completedProfile === false && (
 )}

```
  {/* Navigator with profile image */}
  <Actions picture={myUserContext?.picture} />
</main>
```

);
};

export default Profile;

```
The backend sends an object with the isAuthenticated key so in the profile page I can use effect to navigate back to login page if the user is unauthenticated:
```

userRouter.get('/get-user', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
try {
// Check if the user is authenticated
const isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();

```
// Check if req.user exists before using .toObject()
const userObject = req.user ? (req.user as any).toObject() : {};
userObject.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
userObject.customProperty = 'some value';

res.status(200).json(userObject);
```

} catch (error) {
next(error);
}
});

```
 Here it comes the issues. I cannot get the data on mobile... I dont know how to do it. I added the use effect, and checked if the user is not authenticated. outside, if the user is undefined, I set the loading indicator. Because apparently, the mobile browser does not replace with data if the axios founded meanwhile the data. So if I log the myUserContext in the Profile page I will get an undefined, and than the user object. The browser remains to the undefined line only.
```

const Profile = () => {
const myUserContext = useContext(userContext);
const navigate = useNavigate();
console.log(myUserContext);

useEffect(() => {
if (myUserContext?.isAuthenticated === false) {
navigate('/login');
}
}, [myUserContext, navigate])

if (myUserContext === undefined) return

## Loading...

return (

{ myUserContext?.completedProfile === false && (
 )}
{/* Navigator with profile image */}


);
};

```
https://car-share.vercel.app/
```

Comment: OMG... I cannot belive the format of this..

Comment: Sorry for this, but i don't know how to reformat this. I think the best way is to put here the github page:
https://github.com/ddmihai/car-share-ride-frontend/tree/main/src